# Add widget below Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, position

How can I add widget below the card(the circle part)?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: 
      Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 250,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Text(
                    "Report",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 80,
            left: 24,
            right: 24,
            child: Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              child: Container(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                color: const Color(0xff000066),
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(Icons.analytics_outlined)),
                            Text(
                              "Report A",
                              style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff000066)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              color: const Color(0xff000066),
                              icon: Icon(Icons.report_problem_outlined),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Report B",
                              style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff000066)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              color: const Color(0xff000066), 
                              icon: Icon(Icons.report),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            Text("Report C",
                                style:
                                    TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff000066))),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                color:const Color(0xff000066), 
                                icon: Icon(Icons.work),
                                onPressed: () {}),
                            Text("Report D",
                                style:
                                    TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff000066))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                    )),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Should I continue using `Positioned` or there are others good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your Card and the following Widgets in a Column:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 250,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text(
                      "Report",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 80,
              left: 24,
              right: 24,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Card(...),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.amber.shade300,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text('My other widget.'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I notice the position of the card is different between you and mine. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: This is due to the fact that your first `Positioned` Widget (the background) has a fixed `height: 250` while your `Card` has a fixed  `aspectRatio`. Hence, the look and feel will depend on the width of the screen. You should probably use an `aspectRatio`  for the background too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column` for the widget which is at the bottom and give `padding` as per your need. then you can continue as usual programming.